# Fazer uma procedure SQL Server recebendo string com caracter especial e obtendo apenas os números

Tags: sql-server, asp

Olá, estou com um sistema desenvolvido em ASP Clássico, no qual eu seleciono até 5 horários em uma tela.
Esses horários são enviados à outra página via querystring, porém o formato que vem é seguido por uma exclamação. Exemplo 7!10!19!
O que preciso é pegar esses códigos (7, 10 e 19) e usá-los para inserir um registro em uma tabela SQL Server com cada um deles.

Estou tentando fazer isso via procedure, pois meus conhecimentos em ASP são muuuuito pequenos.

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie primeiramente uma função para dividir sua string em valores separados:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.splitstring ( @separador CHAR, @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX) )
  RETURNS
  @returnList TABLE ([Name] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN

  DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
  DECLARE @pos INT

  WHILE CHARINDEX(@separador, @stringToSplit) > 0
    BEGIN
    SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(@separador, @stringToSplit)  
    SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

    INSERT INTO @returnList 
    SELECT @name

    SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
 END

 INSERT INTO @returnList
 SELECT @stringToSplit

 RETURN
END
```

Chame a função criada passando uma string contendo os valores separados por "!":

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.splitstring('!', '91!12!65!78!56!789')
```

O resultado para essa consulta será esse abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para inserir os valores em sua outra tabela, basta adaptar o seguinte comando de acordo com as colunas que você tem em sua tabela:

```
INSERT INTO TabelaDeDestino SELECT Name FROM dbo.splitstring('!', '91!12!65!78!56!789')
```

*Essa é uma adaptação da resposta em inglês https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string*

Comment: Muito obrigada Ulysses! Já me ajuda muuuuito!!!!! :D